# Is there a way of using the ImportExcel Module in Powershell to access a Excel document in a Sharepoint Document Library?

Tags: powershell

I'm currently trying to run a PowerShell script which will take excel data from a SharePoint document library and insert it into a SQL database. I'm trying to use the importExcel module in PowerShell, as I think that has the ability to get data from SharePoint if the link is written in a certain way, however I can't get it working and it displays the error: "file not found"

I've been trying to do this with a link written like this:

```
$path = "\\organisation.sharepoint.com\sites\Deliveries-Team Name\Shared Documents\Spreadsheet name.xlsx"
$Workplace = Import-Excel $path -worksheetname "worksheet"
```

This also doesn't work if I use:

```
https://organisation.sharepoint.com/sites/Deliveries-Team Name/Shared Documents/Spreadsheet name.xlsx
```

When I run this using both however I get a error saying  "file not found". Does anyone know what the format of the path has to look like for this to work with the importExcel module in powershell?

Just for information, I have tried also doing this using this approach: New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application and when running it in task scheduler it was a bit tempermental on whether it would run or not(thought it would work with the path https://organisation.sharepoint.com/sites/Deliveries-Team Name/Shared Documents/Spreadsheet name.xlsx), so would prefer if it can be done with importexcel.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Use File Explorer to locate the file.  It you cannot find the file with File Explorer you will either need to make the file shared or download the file before using.

Comment: You could also use, Test-Path or Get-ChildItem commands to verify the file is available or not. If it is already a shared path, make sure you have access for it.